# what is the reason behind VersionError: No matching document found for id - on save with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have been trying to resolve a bug where my mongoose Model object wont save to database with error, VersionError: No matching document found for id.

I really can't tell the difference between the code that was not working and the one working.

```
await ModelObject.create(object.property); // this does not work
await ModelObject.create({ ...object.property }); // this works
```

I have logged both to console and they give 100% identical objects
Is there any secrets behind this or I'm missing out on something ?